# Text formatting as number is read incorrectly using a VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for your help in advance. I haven't stumbled across a post dealing with this, so maybe I'm asking the wrong question. I have quite a specific problem using Excel with my own VBA code. I'm writing a budget script, which has an item code '010'.

I'm using a script to process line items per code (not necessary to go into details here). Now, my problem is that I typecast the code as text in the source sheet by using ='010.

However, when I pull the data across into the destination sheet using the script, it always displays 10.

My question is - how can I prevent this? Please note that the budget code is set by our clients, so I cannot possibly change this.

Much appreciated and kind regards

Comment: What's the code you're using to get the `010`?

Comment: Can you use something like this `=TEXT(010,"000")` in the destination cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking out for a Solution in `Excel-VBA`, then here it is..

```
Sub test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Rng.NumberFormat = "000"
End Sub
```